# How to use a stored procedure to retrieve the largest CustID number then add 1 to this returned CustID number and display this in the CustID textbox

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I need to do exactly as the title says, I have created the stored procedure as shown below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindMaxCustID    
AS
SELECT max(CustID) 
FROM Customer
```

Now I just need to call it and add 1 to the returned CustID, then display it in my txtCustID textbox. This is what I have so far...

```
Clear();
command.Connection = conn;
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = "FindMaxCustID";
```

But now I am stuck, I don't know how to code it.

Comment: What is it you don't know how to do? Call an SQLCommand? Add text to a TextBox? It seems like you already got the "hard" part done. Also of note, you could use the following in your SQL instead: `SELECT max(CustID) + 1`. That way, you won't have to add one in your code.

Comment: In reply to Tobberoth, I don't know how to add the returned value to a text box.

Comment: The problem is this FindMaxCustID may not be truly max CustID. What if two users call this procedure at the same time? It will return same CustID to 2 users and it will not be unique anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help you execute your procedure and return an int (CustId) which you can increment as you wish.

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("FindMaxCustID", connection)) {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      connection .Open();
      var result =  cmd.ExecuteScalar(); // you'll get the first cell on the first row. Cast to the correct type

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the stored procedure to this:

SELECT ISNULL(MAX(custId), 0) + 1 FROM Customer

And then is simply a matter of running the Command  class ExecuteScalar method and get the value. But, as someone as pointed before, using an stored procedure for this is way too overkill.